# InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression could not be translated, even though I used ToListAsync() - EF Core 3.1

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have this code in my repository:

```
public async Task<IndexViewModel> GetAllPosts(int pageNumber, string category)
{
    Func<Post, bool> InCategory = (post) => post.Category.Equals(category, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    int pageSize = 5;
    int skipAmount = pageSize * (pageNumber - 1);

    var query = dbContext.Posts.AsQueryable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        query = query.Where(x => InCategory(x));

    return new IndexViewModel()
    {
        Posts = await query
            .Skip(skipAmount)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToListAsync()
    }; 
}
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(p => Invoke(__InCategory_0, p[Post]) )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/linkid=2101038 for more information.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, ref <>c__DisplayClass8_0 )

Now this is despite the fact that I used `.ToListAsync()`, which it tells me to use in the error. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Expression` if you expect execution this on the server side. Also, usually, database has case insensitiive collation and you don't have to worry about case.

```cs
public async Task<IndexViewModel> GetAllPosts(int pageNumber, string category)
{
    Expression<Func<Post, bool>> InCategory = (post) => post.Category == category;

    int pageSize = 5;
    int skipAmount = pageSize * (pageNumber - 1);

    var query = dbContext.Posts.AsQueryable();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        query = query.Where(InCategory);

    return new IndexViewModel()
    {
        Posts = await query
            .Skip(skipAmount)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToListAsync()
    }; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that LINQ queries that would have poor performance because a lot of data will have to be loaded into memory are blocked by EFCore.

We can still do it explicitly if we must by calling `AsEnumerable()` before filtering the data like:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(blog => StandardizeUrl(blog.Url).Contains("dotnet"))
    .ToList();
```

This is not recommended unless the data is small, because all of `Blogs` in this example is being loaded into memory.
[Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)